# Pyspark -- mapping a column of type <list> to a column of type list<list>> based on criteria from a different column

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, mapping

I am having a hard time describing exactly what I want. Here is an example.

go from this :

```
name   sport                                    position
Bob    [‘basketball’,’basketball’,’football’]   [‘PG’,’SG’,’QB’]
Jon    [‘hockey’, ‘football’, ‘football’]       [‘LW’, ‘WR’ , ‘TE’]
Tim    [‘baseball’, ‘basketball’]               [‘1B’, ‘PG’]
```

to this:

```
name   sport                                    position
Bob    [‘basketball’,’football’]                [ [‘PG’,’SG’],’QB’]
Jon    [‘hockey’,  ‘football’]                  [‘LW’,[‘WR’ , ‘TE’]] 
Tim    [‘baseball’, ‘basketball’]               [‘1B’, ‘PG’]
```

I thought about doing an 'explode' operation on 'position' and then 'sport', and then a 'groupBy' and an 'agg'. But that creates many unneeded rows, and then I need to do further filtering.

Are there any mapping techniques that could be of use to generate the 'position' column?

( to get a new 'sport' column I jsut need to drop duplicates)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve your requirement by writing a `udf` function as

```
from itertools import groupby
def function(x, y):
    keys = []
    values = []
    for key, group in groupby(zip(x, y), lambda x: x[0]):
        keys.append(key)
        values.append([z[1] for z in list(group)])
    return [keys, values]

udfFunctionCall = F.udf(function, T.ArrayType(T.StringType()))
```

Call the `udf` function creating a `new` column

```
df = df.withColumn("new", udfFunctionCall(df['sport'], df['position']))
```

And `select` the necessary columns as

```
df.select(df.name, df.new[0].alias("sport"), df.new[1].alias("position")).show(truncate=False)
```

You should have your desired output `dataframe` as

```
+----+----------------------+----------------+
|name|sport                 |position        |
+----+----------------------+----------------+
|Bob |[basketball, football]|[[PG, SG], [QB]]|
|Jon |[hockey, football]    |[[LW], [WR, TE]]|
|Tim |[baseball, basketball]|[[1B], [PG]]    |
+----+----------------------+----------------+
```